# CABasicAnimation with array of frames

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, calayer, cabasicanimation

I have a `CABasicAnimation` with a `.fromValue` and a `.toValue` that move in an PNG image with 202 images and display them one by one

also i used `CALayer` to hold the image.png

the problem that it pass all the images by sequence
i want to display the images by frames that i will put in an `NSArray`

here is my code:

```
CABasicAnimation *anim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"sampleIndex"];
anim.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];
anim.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithInt:203];
anim.duration = 1.75f;
anim.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;
anim.autoreverses = YES; 
[myImage addAnimation:anim forKey:nil];
```

and the array of frames is:

```
frames =   (753, 377, 798, 422)  ,
  (706, 377, 751, 422)  ,
  (659, 377, 704, 422)  ,
  (612, 377, 657, 422)  ,
  (565, 377, 610, 422)  ,
  (518, 377, 563, 422)  ,
  (518, 424, 563, 468)  ,
  (471, 424, 516, 468)  ,
  (424, 424, 469, 468)  ,
  (471, 377, 516, 422)  ,
  (424, 377, 469, 422)  ,
  (377, 377, 422, 422)  ,
  (330, 377, 375, 422)  ,
```

and so on ....

Any Ideas ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similarly to your frame array you can add all the needed images(frames) to UIImageView. Here is the example:

```
NSArray *images = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: 
              [UIImage imageNamed:@"frame753.png"],
              [UIImage imageNamed:@"frame377.png"],
              [UIImage imageNamed:@"frame798.png"], 

              nil];
yourImageView.animationImages = images; 
yourImageView.animationDuration = 1.75; 
yourImageView.animationRepeatCount = 0;
[yourImageViewstartAnimating];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have just 1 image contain 202 images

Comment: Consider extracting frames and save as separate images then.

Comment: i dont have a tool to give me frames typically the same !!